# Possible memory leak on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory-leaks

We have a Rails app running on heroku 2x dyno. In Paper-trail logs, the memory consumption of the app keeps on increasing linearly even without a request to the server, which reveals a possible memory leak.

[image]
The Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org

ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'aasm', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'american_date'
gem 'attr_encrypted'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.1'
gem 'bugsnag'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.22.0'
gem 'foreigner', '~> 1.6.1'
gem 'hstore_accessor'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-validation-rails', '~> 1.12.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.0'
gem 'pundit', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'feature'
gem 'finance'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'accountingjs-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 1.3.0'
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'skylight'
end

gem 'newrelic_rpm' #reccommended to load as late as possible

gem 'smarter_csv'
```

The new relic graphs shows the increase in memory usage.

[image]

We tried downgrading ruby version to 2.0 and the usage was incremental down but less  gradual.

Is there any way to find whether the problem is with our code?. What are the possible methods to find the root cause?

**EDIT:* * (config/unicorn.rb)

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |_server, _worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) &&
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |_server, _worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) &&
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: How many Unicorn workers are you running?  Does the issue occur if you reduce the number of workers?  I ask because we were seeing something similar with Puma when we attempted to run more than 2 workers.

Comment: @tagCincy I think heroku sets up the unicorn workers. In our config file, it says `worker_processes Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 3)`.

Comment: Actually that line says it is defaulting to 3 workers unless you set the WEB_CONCURRENCY config.  Try setting up that config with `heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=2`

Answer (score 1):

This week I resolved this very same problem on an application of mine. The culprit was Ruby 2.1 (in my case it was 2.1.5). I fixed this by switching to Ruby 2.0.

See the difference in graphs (the green line marks the moment of the switch):

[image: Increase in performance after switching from Ruby 2.1.5 back to Ruby 2.0]

After the change, I moved from 10*2X dynos to 3*1X dynos without a noticeable performance hit.

If you do some online research, you'll find Ruby 2.1 has been plagued with memory leaks (across all patchlevel versions). I don't know if 2.2 is any better.

I also suspect the `attr_encrypted` gem may have something to do with this. Coincidentally, my application also uses it. My theory is that either the gem itself, a dependency of it or (most probably) the underlying Ruby core libraries may do something that makes this leak more apparent.

Comment: We tried downgrading before but didn't show a significant improvement in mem usage. But the rate at which the memory increases was less.